# Having line by line words in a text file

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfilechooser, filewriter

```
JButton btnExport = new JButton("Export");
        btnExport.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {     

                JFileChooser saver = new JFileChooser("");      
                int returnVal = saver.showSaveDialog(null);
                File file = saver.getSelectedFile();   
                 BufferedWriter writer = null; 
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
                 {  
                    try  
                    {  

                    writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( file.getAbsolutePath().toString() + "\n")); 
                    writer.write( jTextArea1.getText());         
                    writer.newLine();
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close( );  
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Text was Saved Successfully!",  
                                "Success!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);  
                    }  
                    catch (Exception e)  
                    {  
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Text could not be Saved!",  
                                "Error!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);  
                    }  
                }   
        }});
```

I have tried several codes but when i input in a textarea line by line and try to save it in a text file, it will still be a single line. Can anyone help me? I want the text to be line by line in my textfile. Thank you

Comment: Try using [JTextArea#write](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write(java.io.Writer)). Don't forget, if you have line/word wrap enabled, that doesn't constitute a new line in the file

Comment: I'm still new to it. How am I am going to disable the line or word wrap. Hmmm seems confusing because I am going to save them inside a single text file

Comment: How are entering the text in text area? are you using enter key to write in new line?

Comment: Yes, I key in the text file and then, when I click a button I can save the input of the text area to the textfile (line in line format). Same goes to text area..

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it, but I would first see if:

```
jTextArea1.write(writer);
```

gives the desired file output as per the javadocs here:

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write(java.io.Writer)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write%28java.io.Writer%29)

If *that* doesn't correctly use the same line breaks as the JTextArea, then you could use a brute force approach and loop through the lines in the control one at a time like so:

```
String text = jTextArea.getText();
for( int i=0; i < jTextArea.getLineCount(); ++i) {
    int start = jTextArea.getLineStartOffset(i);
    int end = jTextArea.getLineEndOffset(i);
    String line = text.substring(start, end);
    writer.write(line);
    writer.newLine();
}
```

**Edit:**

I have just tested this to confirm, and both approaches yield the same line break positions (so the succinct `jTextArea1.write(writer)` is naturally preferable). Note that both approaches ignore auto-inserted line wrap locations, and only save carriage returns to the written file wherever the enter key was used during text input.

If, for some unusual reason, it is desirable to actually save the locations of the line wrapping in the output file you would need to measure the width of text based on the width of the JTextArea using the `LineBreakMeasurer` class. The official tutorial for this can be found here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/drawmulstring.html

However, note that if you do this, you will be inserting hard line breaks into the saved file where there was only ever soft line wrapping originally, so loading your saved data back into the JTextArea will not exactly reproduce the original input.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **FileWriter** use **OutputStreamWriter**, your problem will be solved as OutputStreamWriter consdiers '\n' while streaming.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("path"));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help. I will try this and search on the OutputStreamWriter, I should read more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileWriter to write string to the files.
Below code works fine.

```
package areaText;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class TextAreaTest extends JFrame{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TextAreaTest().createFrame();

    }

    private void createFrame() {
        setSize(200,200);
        setLayout(null);
        final JTextArea area=new JTextArea("Test");
        area.setSize(50, 50);
        area.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
        add(area);

        JButton  button=new JButton("Save");
        button.setBounds(100, 100, 80, 30);
        add(button);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String s=area.getText();
                System.out.println("GOT-"+s);
                try {
                    File f=new File("testFile.txt");
                    System.out.println("Writing "+f.getAbsolutePath());
                    FileWriter fr=new FileWriter(f);
                    fr.write(s);
                    fr.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: The use of null layouts is highly discouraged, especially to new/inexperienced developers

Comment: I just created this to solve the problem of writing Text area content to text file, I am not explaining layout here. And ya I am not a Swing programmer